# Something like $CDPATH that works for all bash commands

Tags: bash, command-line, autocomplete

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can get `$CDPATH` working for every command-line tool. At the moment, I have a directory in my homedir that's called `src/` which contains all of my projects. This way I can type `cd <foo>` from any directory, as opposed to having to type `cd ~/src/foo` every time.

I'd like to be able to do something like `vim foo/bar.c` and have bash automatically figure out what I mean. Additionally, I'd like to be able to go `vim foo/<Tab>` and have it give me suggestions for what I want to edit through autocomplete, and I'd also like to be able to go `vim fo<Tab>` and have it autocomplete the rest of `foo` for me.

Is there a pre-existing autocomplete script for something like this? I've tried making one of my own but it doesn't do quite what I want. If possible, I'd also like for it to autocomplete subdirectories like `foo/baz/thing.c`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried.

Comment: I'm afraid I tried this a while ago and I deleted the script and gave up after I discovered CDPATH.

Comment: you could do `(cd foo; vim bar.c)`. Not exactly what you want, but a step in the right direction. You could then write a bash function or script so that you can do `my-edit foo bar.c`

Comment: This still wouldn't work for all commands, though. I want to be able to use stuff like `touch`, `objdump`, `cp`, `mv`, basically anything.

Comment: you could create a script/function that allows `my vim foo bar.c`, now all parts are arguments. You would also have to add bash completion mode rules. (change name from `my`, no something that makes sense.)

Comment: You would need a way in your shell to trigger an event after all the expansions are done but before the command is actually executed. I do not think that bash provides such a hook.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, I don't think there is an easy way to do this transparently for any command.

You could create a wrapper script and call it, say, `f`, so you can do

```
f() {
    local command=$1; shift
    local files=() arg file
    for arg in "$@"; do
        file=$(some method to look up the current file in $CDPATH)
        files+=("$file")
    done
    "$command" "${files[@]}"
}

f vim foo.c bar.h
```

Of course, this has no knowledge of options or non-filename arguments (i.e. this does not let to do `grep -i pattern foo.c`) and you'll have to think about what to do if the argument cannot be found in a CDPATH directory.